# Create a View with the identifier as a variable on u-sql

Tags: u-sql

I would like to create a view using U-SQL. The name of the view can only be defined at compile time using the DECLARE function.

Visual Studio throws a syntax error when i try to use the variable in the create view statement.

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

U-SQL does not support dynamic U-SQL at this point although if you feel this is an important missing feature you could post a feature request here:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/327234-data-lake

It looks like there is already a similar request you can vote for [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/327234-data-lake/suggestions/16828864-dynamic-u-sql-statement-support).

As a workaround, you could generate the U-SQL dynamically then run the script separately either manually or using one of the SDKs eg using Powershell, .net.  A simple example:

```
//Dynamic U-SQL
DECLARE @viewName string = "dbo.vw_yourViewName";

// Create dynamic U-SQL
@usql = 
        SELECT * 
        FROM ( VALUES
            ( "USE DATABASE yourDatabase;"),
            ( String.Format("DROP VIEW IF EXISTS {0};", @viewName)),
            ( String.Format("CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS {0} AS EXTRACT col1 int, col2 string, col3 string, col4 string, col5 string FROM \"/input/input44.txt\" USING Extractors.Csv();", @viewName))
             ) AS  x (usql);


// Output the statements in the correct sort order
OUTPUT @usql
TO "/output/dynamic.usql" 
USING Outputters.Text(delimiter:' ', quoting:false);
```

Other examples of dynamic U-SQL (or more precisely, U-SQL generated dynamically) are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43227421/u-sql-split-a-csv-file-to-multiple-files-based-on-distinct-values-in-file/43243301#comment73604351_43243301) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45754420/dynamic-from-in-u-sql-statement).